# How can i pass multiple commands same time in this code

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run cmd from local folder and wanted to pass multiple commands at the same time Eg: once i'm able to run this command, p.StandardInput.WriteLine("multichain-util create chain34");after executing this i want to pass this command p.StandardInput.WriteLine("multichai-cli chain 34 -daemon")

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\multichain-windows-2.0.2";
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.Start();
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine("multichain-util create chain34");
        p.StandardInput.Flush();
        p.StandardInput.Close();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "multiple commands at the same time".

Comment: once i'm able to run this command, p.StandardInput.WriteLine("multichain-util create chain34"); i want to pass this command p.StandardInput.WriteLine("multichai-cli chain 34 -daemon");

Comment: If I understand this correctly (which I may not), I would skip cmd.exe and run the multichain executables directly one after the other.  There are dot-net wrappers for the multichain API but I couldn't find the functionality multichain-util provides.

Answer (score 0):

Move all process related stuff into a method. Take in a list of commands as a parameter for that command. And then instead of one `p.StandardInput.WriteLine()`, iterate through the list of commands and write them all.

```
static void Main()
{
    var commands = new List<string>() { "dir", "mkdir ABC", "dir" };
    ExecuteCmd(commands);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void ExecuteCmd(List<string> commands)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();

    foreach (var comm in commands)
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine(comm);

    p.StandardInput.Flush();
    p.StandardInput.Close();
    p.WaitForExit();

    Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```